# How do I unlock all of the arcade machines?

Tags: duck-game

The singleplayer mode of Duck Game is a bunch of challenges, represented by arcade machines. You get two to start out, and completing all of the challenges on one of those two unlocks a third one.

However, there's a bunch of other arcade machines that I haven't been able to unlock so far (I got at least Silver on every challenge I have available). How do I unlock them all?

Answer (score 1):

It's honestly difficult to say. Looking at this [Steam Community discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/312530/discussions/0/618463738406513590/), it's difficult to tell the exact conditions required to unlock them.

One post there, though, describes in detail how they unlock.

> They unlock weirdly. To unlock more after the first 3 you need
>   everything on gold and at least 5 platinums from those. After that
>   you'l unlock a bonus challenge map of the first obstacle course. Do
>   that and you'l get another arcade machine. From them you just need to
>   beat each level in all of the available arcade machines to unlock
>   more, you don't need any gold or platinum medals. **[x](http://steamcommunity.com/app/312530/discussions/0/618463738406513590/#c618463738406782492)**

What I would personally recommend is to try going through each unlocked arcade machine through a more systematic approach. Try reaching for gold/platinum in the earlier challenges before moving on to the next ones. From there, you may be able to unlock the rest of the arcade machines.